# What does SDL_RenderClear do?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, game-development

I'm Using the SDL library in C to learn some game dev , however i'm quite confused as to what SDL_RenderClear does and when do we use it. I did check the SDL documentation about the same , however i still wasn't able to understand where exactly we would use it and what is its use.

Answer (score 2):

It's like rendering background color to color you have set via another API namely `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` as you already found on documentation online.

Imagine you have rendered several things on screen. To begin again, you need to clear it to start over. Underlying of `SDL_RenderClear` wraps specific native platform your application runs on top, it can be OpenGL, DirectX, etc. It helps in communicating with such specific function that platform provides in order for you to flexibly clear your screen without a need to know low level functions, and use SDL2 for other things else like windowing, inputs from keyboard/mouse/joysticks, sound, and even utility functions related to rendering to aid your own rendering implementation.

---

To add a few more, SDL2 provides minimal but optimized rendering capability. `SDL_RenderClear` is one of those several functions you can use in rendering category. Anyway, you can decide to go on integrating with what you prefer i.e. OpenGL, DirectX, Vulkan etc. yourself.